# scroll method not working on ipad

Tags: jquery, ios, ipad, scroll

I have the following code to rotate a button when reaching the bottom of the document page, which is working everywhere but on ios devices. Anyone could help?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($("body").height() == ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop())) {
            $(".next").addClass('rotated').bind('click touchstart', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();               
                pageScroller.goTo(1);   
            });
        } else {
        $(".next").removeClass('rotated');
        }
    });
});
```